# How to find only school results in google autocomplete api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api

I want to search only schools in google autocomplete api. I have tried but it does not filter the search specific to schools only. I have read from below url

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

But it has only `types` parameters for filtering results.

I am able to search only schools in google nearby places search but it requires me to send lat, long but I want to search all schools despite of any location.

Comment: Did you want to search School names ??

Comment: Yes. Only schools

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present time Places API autocomplete doesn't support filtering by types like school, restaurant, etc.

There is a feature request in Google issue tracker to make it possible filter autocomplete by types that are supported in Places API searches:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35820774

As you can see the feature request was filed in 2011. Unfortunately, it looks like Google didn't set a high priority on this task. I would suggest starring the feature request to add your vote. Hopefully Google will implement it one day.

Comment: Would it be possible to get the Place ID of the places returned via Places autocomplete then find the place type using the place ID and filter it by simply appending to an array or something?

Comment: I’ve been looking a bit more and Google does seem to give the place type in the returned JSON data when using autocomplete. I’m assuming you could just code a filter https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete

Comment: @Junaid Google doesn't have a detailed place type in autocomplete response. They just give you generic types like geocode, establishment, etc. You cannot know if this is a school using this field.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that now. If you still wanted to filter results could u just get the place ID if each place then get the place type using that. It looks like it should work?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I found working for me. It is not ideal, but better than nothing

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=MY-APP-KEY&query=shaheen%20public&types=school`

Comment: I think this is sadly probably the best you can do with the Google APIs for school search.  The results from the various APIs for schools seem to be very poor quality for some reason.  The results for `nearbysearch` and `findplacefromtext` are similarly bad, and usually only return a single incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?key=MY-APP-KEY&query=shaheen%20public&types=school
```

Read more about supported types here.

https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types?csw=1

Answer (score 0):

Google Places Autocomplete API still doesn't support filtering by types. What we use is a bit of a workaround.

What it comes down to is fetching autocomplete predictions for a given input and then filtering the results to only get schools.

```js
// types used in filtering autocomplete results
const schoolPlaceTypes = [
  'school',
  'secondary_school',
  'university',
]

// input event handler
// DEBOUNCE THIS
const searchSchool = async (key, query) => {
  const requestUrl = encodeURI(`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?key=${key}&language=fr&input=${query}`)
  
  try {
    // fetch all predictions for a given input
    const response = await fetch(requestUrl, { method: 'GET' })
    const { predictions } = await response.json()
    // get all predictions that match at least on of the targeted types
    const results = predictions
      .filter(({ types }) => types.some(type => schoolPlaceTypes.includes(type)))
      // OPTIONAL: format filtered places to return only what is needed.
      .map(({ structured_formatting, place_id, types }) => ({
      place_id,
      name: structured_formatting.main_text,
      address: structured_formatting.secondary_text,
      types,
    }))

    return results
  }
  catch(e) {
    console.error(e)
    return []
  }
}
```